# Ajax script for deleting records from the database does not work

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I wrote a script that should delete a specific entry. The problem is that when you click on the delete button, the record does not disappear, you have to reload the page to make it disappear. And only the first record in the database is deleted, for example, if I click delete the record with id = 2, then the record with id = 1 will be deleted. And I just can not understand why this is happening.

This is my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("body").on("click","#delete",function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            var id = $(this).data('data-id');
            var token = $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content");

            $.ajax({
                url: "{{route('deletePost',['id' => $post->id])}}",
                type: 'DELETE',
                data: {_token: token, id: id},
                success: function (response){
                    $("#deletePost").html(response.message);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Method

```
public function delete($id) {
    $post = Profile::find($id);
    $post->delete();
    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'deleted...'
    ]);
}
```

Route

```
Route::delete('/id{id}/delete', 'ProfileController@delete')->name('deletePost');
```

And html

```
<form action="{{route('deletePost', ['id' => $post->id])}}" method="post" id="formDelete">
    @csrf @method('DELETE')
    <button type="submit" id="delete" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger py-0 mt-4" data-id="{{ $post->id }}">Удалить</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Is your form inside a foreach or any kind of loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

> var id = $(this).data('data-id');

to

> var id = $(this).data('id');

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("body").on("click","#delete",function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            var id = $(this).data('id');
            var token = $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content");

            $.ajax({
                url: "delete/"+id,
                type: 'DELETE',
                data: {_token: token, id: id},
                success: function (response){
                    $("#deletePost").html(response.message);
             // call your data get function here for disappear record after delele

                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Change the route to :

```
Route::delete('delete/{id}', 'ProfileController@delete')->name('deletePost');
```

Delete Method are just fine.
There are no need form for delete button

```
<button type="submit" id="delete" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger py-0 mt-4" data-id="{{ $post->id }}">Удалить</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, now the necessary posts are deleted, they are only deleted after page reload

Answer (score 1):

You wrongly access attribute `data-id` of button delete.
It should be

```
var id = $(this).data('id');
```

Or

```
var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
```